# Blogspot noindex search label

Tags: seo, google-search, robots.txt, googlebot, google-index

The default *robots.txt* of Blogspot is:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow: 
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
Allow: /
Sitemap: http://castbird-sourcing.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?orderby=UPDATED
```

But when I [site:castbird-sourcing.blogspot.com](http://castbird-sourcing.blogspot.com) the Google search show something like:

```
In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 32 already displayed.
If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included.
```

When I expand the result, I see something like:

```
castbird-sourcing.blogspot.com/search/label/gadget
A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more.
```

My questions are:

1. does this very similar to the 32 already displayed problem harm the
   SEO in general?
2. shouldn't Googlebot have already ignored everything
   `/search`? Why do Google still indexing these pages?
3. How do I completely remove indexed `/search` link from the Google result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does this very similar to the 32 already displayed problem harm the
>   seo in general?

Google decides which page to show among those with similar content based on user's query and other algorithms. For example, if a user searches for gadgets and you have a label page for gadgets, that would be a more appropriate result than specific post pages from your blog.

See [this](http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-duplicate-content-wont-hurt-you-unless-it-is-spammy-167459) page.

> Matt Cutts said twice that you should not stress about it, in the
>   worse non-spammy case, Google may just ignore the duplicate content.
>   Matt said in the video, “I wouldn’t stress about this unless the
>   content that you have duplicated is spammy or keyword stuffing.”

.

> shouldn't googlebot have already ignored everything /search? Why do
>   google still indexing these pages?

See [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en) page.

> While Google won't crawl or index the content of pages blocked by
>   robots.txt, we may still index the URLs if we find them on other pages
>   on the web. As a result, the URL of the page and, potentially, other
>   publicly available information such as anchor text in links to the
>   site, or the title from the Open Directory Project (www.dmoz.org), can
>   appear in Google search results.

.

> How do I completely remove indexed /search link from the google
>   result?

I'm not sure if it works but you can try the method [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419). However, I would suggest that you leave the pages as they are and they won't cause any harm to your seo. There are many Blogger blogs which perform well in SERPs even though Google has the label search pages added to its database.